# How can I let jenkins run `bash` command on windows?

Tags: windows, bash, jenkins

I have setup a jenkins server on windows10 pro and installed ubuntu bash on the system. And I created a `Executable windows batch command` and put the command `bash -c ls` there. When executing this job I got below error:

```
c:\jenkins\workspaces>bash -c ls 
'bash' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

It says that `bash` is not recognized as an internal or external command. Then I tried to use the absolute path but still not work. The error is shown as below:

```
c:\jenkins\workspaces>C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe -c ls 
'C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I can run the command manually on windows. How can I configure this on jenkins? I need to run the build command from windows normal command window and in my build script it needs to launch a process inside bash.

Comment: Have you tried to login into the server as the jenkins user and see if the command is available (the jenkins user configuration normally avoids some system commands)? If it is not available as jenkins user you should configure the jenkins user permissions.

Comment: I have configured the jenkins service account to be the same as login account. I expect Jenkins is using the same user to run the command. But I
 am not sure about it. How to verify the name of the jenkins user?

Comment: The jenkins service can launch jobs locally or to other available nodes. If you launch jobs locally it will use the user that has started the jenkins server (from what you say, the login user). If you have configured extra nodes you can check the login user at Jenkins > Manage > Manage Nodes > Select Node > Configuration.

Comment: In any case, after checking the user, you should also check if the environment and the tools are correctly setup under the Global Tool configuration and under the Node Configuration.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, jenkins flips out when trying to run wsl ubuntu commands from a batch file using bash. Jenkins also seems to take issue with bat files that open multiple cmd windows... pretty big problem when you've spent months developing a script locally.

Answer (score 1):

You could install MsysGit, which includes bash, and in Jenkins you have to set the shell executable, which is the path to the `sh.exe`

You could also install cygwin, but i think this uses high amount of RAM for just running bash scripts.

Answer (score 0):

similiar to what @Borislav said, a migrated shell might help, if you had `mingw` or `msys2` and start your `java -jar slave.jar` from that bash console, you should be able to directly chose to `execute shell`, just considering it to be a linux node at your jenkins

Answer (score -1):

Try to install git. Git hold a minimal bash environment which can help in your case.
https://git-scm.com/

Comment: OP has *"installed ubuntu bash on the system"*

Comment: I know, but he don't know if the problem comes from ubuntu bash itself.

Comment: *"I can run the command manually on windows"* This is almost certainly a permissions issue. Adding GIT, just to run bash, is just avoiding the point.